# How to create a pre/post dummy?

Tags: regression

I have pre and post measures of the same participants, divided over a Treatment condition and a control condition (no treatment). I have calculated the diff-in-diff by hand and want to know if this is significant.

Therefore, I want to perform a regression with a Treatment dummy (1= treatment, 0=no treatment), a Time dummy (1=post test, 0= prestest) and and the interaction between both. My dependent variable is a math test score.

I know how to create the Treatment dummy. 
My question is about the Time dummy: Every participant is measured pre and post, so I have 2 columns of math score data in my spss file. I would like to know how to create the Time dummy, as every participant is measured at both times (pre and post).

(I know how to create a dummy variable in spss, but I dont know what the Time dummy should look like).

Comment: At the moment this question is quite unclear to me. Could you explain a little more about your set-up? Are you asking for help with how to create dummies in your statistical software (which would be off-topic here) or just a conceptual question about what the dummies should look like when set up?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Hi Silverfish, I have registered my Cinta account. Is my question still on hold?

Comment: This question is now in the review queue so that people can see if it is sufficiently clear and on-topic. I think that it should be, now it's clear that it's the data format that is the issue rather than the specific software.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how you do this in SPSS but you need to have a single column for your outcome with two columns for your predictors: one for treatment and one for time. You would also need a column to identify the person so you can specify the repeated measures nature of your data-set. It way well be that SPSS would let you do the analysis with the data-set in the format that you have but you would need to ask on an SPSS-specific forum.